# Google Charts - how to add a fixed scale on an axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm having trouble scaling my chart correctly. My chart represents data for every hour of the day in a 24 hour format, meaning that I need the numbers 0-24 on my linechart.

I've tried adding the `logScale`, `minValue` and `maxValue` properties to the `hAxis`, but nothing is working.

As you can see on the chart, the `hour` axis is not spanning a fixed axis from `0-24` hours, but instead from `9-15` hours.

[image: the chart]

I also only have 3 rows in my data set, which reside on the hours `9`, `14` and `15`. Despite this, the lines are spanning from `9-14` as if they have values; however there is no data there, so the lines should be running along the bottom at `0` between these two points.

How can I put a fixed horizontal scale on my chart, and have individual values on my lines for each hour?

Here's my code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
    var json = $.getJSON('my JSON data link', function(data)
    {
        var chartStructure = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var chartData = [];

        chartStructure.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
        chartStructure.addColumn('number', 'Pageviews');
        chartStructure.addColumn('number', 'Unique Pageviews');
        chartStructure.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        chartStructure.addColumn('number', 'Earnings in $AUD');

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            chartData[i] = [];
            chartData[i][0] = parseInt(data[i].hour);
            chartData[i][1] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
            chartData[i][2] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
            chartData[i][3] = parseFloat(data[i].sales);
            chartData[i][4] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
            // These chartData values are not correct because I am testing

            chartStructure.addRows(chartData);
        }

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                'minValue': 0, 
                'maxValue': 24
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('todays-total-sales'));

        chart.draw(chartStructure, options);
    });
}

$(window).resize(function()
{
    drawChart();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `viewWindow`.

```
hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      viewWindow:{
          max:1000,
          min:-100
      }
    },
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pszbabey/)

**UPDATE**

If you are using *MaterialCharts* please note that the options have [different syntax](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)!

In order for you to be able to use the classic options, you need to change

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

to

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/pszbabey/14/) is your updated fiddle.

Comment: I just tried that and nothing registered, not even the title

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: If I did I would have to delete the JSON function, because I don't want to share my data. Is it okay if I do that?

Comment: It's throwing errors when I try to create an array, and I can't get it to work. You have a go: https://jsfiddle.net/pszbabey/13/

Comment: Just a thought about your data. Why are you parsing it like that, instead of just arranging the JSON in valid format for Google Charts from the beginning?

Comment: @HenrikAronsson What do you mean?

Comment: @StoyanDekov I just saw your update, and it works. Thanks for the help!

The only problem is that the values for each line are not independent. Each line still spans from `9-14` as if they had values; whereas they should they should be at `0`.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var options = {
                title: "Posted Memes",
                width: 450,
                height: 300,
                is3D:true,
                bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
                legend: { position: "none" },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'No of Memes',
                    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                    viewWindow: {
                        max: 180,
                        min: 0,
                        interval: 1,
                    },

                }

            };
```